# Tabbed menus with checkboxes: one menu is checking another menu's, but not its own

Tags: html, css, checkbox, html-lists

I am running in to an issue on a site where I've got 3 different tabs within a page, and they all have the same menu at the top of it, that includes checkboxes. The intent of it is to check off certain filters for a search. The checkboxes are styled to look more like radio buttons, but function as a normal checkbox.

On the first tab, it works as intended - checking it will display the checked image. When someone chooses another tab, it hides the contents of the currently active tab, and displays the contents of the selected tab. Any of the checkboxes in the other tabs, though, end up checking the box in the first tab, which I can see if I click back over to the first one. The checkbox in the other tab I actually clicked, though, looks unchecked.

I've tried to target very specifically with the CSS, and no matter how long or specific I make the selectors, I can't get the :checked rules to apply. Everything else works fine - I can remove the stylings and do other things to the checkboxes in the other tabs. Just unable to get the :checked state to apply. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here's some code for example:

HTML - portion of the first tab's checklist including checkboxes

```
                    <div id="active_deals" class=""> 
                    <div class="sector_filters_wrapper">
                        <ul class="sector_filters1">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="commerce" name="commerce" />
                                <label for="commerce"><span></span>Commerce & Industry</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="consumergoods" name="consumergoods" />
                                <label for="consumergoods"><span></span>Consumer Goods</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="energy" name="energy" />
                                <label for="energy"><span></span>Energy</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="financial" name="financial" />
                                <label for="financial"><span></span>Financial</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sector_icons1">
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/commerceicon.png" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/consumergoodsicon.png" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/energyicon.png" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/financialicon.png" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sector_filters2">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="healthcare" name="healthcare" />
                                <label for="healthcare"><span></span>Healthcare</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="materials" name="materials" />
                                <label for="materials"><span></span>Materials</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="services" name="services" />
                                <label for="services"><span></span>Services</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="technology" name="technology" />
                                <label for="technology"><span></span>Technology</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
<!-- The code continues to close out the div, etc.. -->
```

HTML for second tab

```
                    <div id="all_deals" class=""> 
                    <div class="sector_filters_wrapper">
                        <ul class="sector_filters1">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="commerce" name="commerce" />
                                <label for="commerce"><span></span>Commerce & Industry</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="consumergoods" name="consumergoods" />
                                <label for="consumergoods"><span></span>Consumer Goods</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="energy" name="energy" />
                                <label for="energy"><span></span>Energy</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="financial" name="financial" />
                                <label for="financial"><span></span>Financial</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sector_icons1">
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/commerceicon.png" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/consumergoodsicon.png" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/energyicon.png" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img align="center" src="images/sector/financialicon.png" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sector_filters2">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="healthcare" name="healthcare" />
                                <label for="healthcare"><span></span>Healthcare</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="materials" name="materials" />
                                <label for="materials"><span></span>Materials</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="services" name="services" />
                                <label for="services"><span></span>Services</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="technology" name="technology" />
                                <label for="technology"><span></span>Technology</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
<!-- this code also continues, similarly to the first one -->
```

CSS

```
#active_deals .sector_filters1 input[type="checkbox"], #active_deals .sector_filters2 input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

#active_deals .sector_filters1 input[type="checkbox"] + label span, #active_deals .sector_filters2 input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:12px;
}

#active_deals .sector_filters1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span, #active_deals .sector_filters2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') -10px top no-repeat;
}


#active_deals .sector_filters1 li label input[type="checkbox"], #active_deals .sector_filters2 li label input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:inline-block;
    width:6px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:12px;
}

#active_deals .sector_filters1 li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked, #active_deals .sector_filters2 li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') -10px top no-repeat;
}



#all_deals .sector_filters1 input[type="checkbox"], #all_deals .sector_filters2 input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

#all_deals .sector_filters1 input[type="checkbox"] + label span, #all_deals .sector_filters2 input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:12px;
}

#all_deals .sector_filters1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span, #all_deals .sector_filters2 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') -10px top no-repeat;
}


#all_deals .sector_filters1 li label input[type="checkbox"], #all_deals .sector_filters2 li label input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:inline-block;
    width:6px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:12px;
}

#all_deals .sector_filters1 li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked, #all_deals .sector_filters2 li label input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background:url('../images/check_radio_sheet.png') -10px top no-repeat;
}
```

I'm lost with what I'm doing wrong, and any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, after tinkering - since I had the label for each option setup with the same name, it was causing the issue to happen. After changing each one to be unique, it's now working properly!